# How can I make an accordion menu with CSS3?

Tags: html, css, accordion

How can I create an expandable menu with only HTML5 and CSS3?

I want to display only 4 menu items and a view all list item, where clicking view all should expand all of the list items.

Comment: Not exactly a drop down but an accordion menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to make it! For example the following.
The HTML looks like this. There is a div, that you click and a div underneath that will expand. This is only possible with the pseudo-selector :target.

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div id="one" class="section">
            <h3>
                    <a href="#one">Heading 1</a>
            </h3>
            <div>
                    <p>Content</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="section">
            <h3>
                    <a href="#two">Heading 2</a>
            </h3>
            <div>
                    <p>Content</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>​




.accordion h3 + div {
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
        -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
        transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
}

.accordion :target h3 + div {
        height: 100px;
}

.accordion .section.large:target h3 + div {
        overflow: auto;
}
```

I made a working Fiddle for you. Have a look at it: [Check me out!](http://jsfiddle.net/x4s2C/)

Answer (score 0):

A well-supported and simpler solution with the `<details />` tag (reference:  [mdn - the Details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details?retiredLocale=it))

```css
details {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0;
}

summary {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: -0.5em -0.5em 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

details[open] {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

details[open] summary {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

Answer (score -1):

My approach with a little js and radio inputs magic. Without any delays, glitches or animation frame drops. With dynamic content height

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion .inner').forEach(p => {
  p.style.marginTop = '-'+p.offsetHeight+'px';
});
```

```css
/* ignore */
body {  
  width: 500px;
}
label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ccffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
label:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
/* end ignore */

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: -20000px;
}
input:checked ~ .content .inner {  
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="item">
    <label for="state1">Button</label>
    <input type="radio" id="state1" name="state" value="1" hidden>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <label for="state2">Button2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="state2" name="state" value="2" hidden>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```