# Attempting to create a second css function - accordion menu

Tags: html, css, menu, accordion

I found this stack conversation:
[accordion with css and html 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715112/how-can-i-make-an-accordion-menu-with-css3)

and it really helped me understand what I was trying to do and I was able to recreate the concept based on their jsfiddle link.

I've since then tried to create my own with success but I am attempting to add a second tier to the accordion - when the portfolio is selected branding and several other options will open, clicking on them will open another accordion div exactly as the first one did. Here is the css I put together:

```
a {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-style:normal;
}

.accordion p + div {
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
        -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
        transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
}

.accordion :target p + div {
        height:auto;
}

/* ---------- SECTION ---------- */

.accordion .section.large:target p + div {
        overflow: auto;
}

.section p{
    color:#FFFfff;
    text-align:right;
    min-width:200px;
    background-color:#2d2d2d;
    font-size:12px;
    font-size-adjust:inherit;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border-top:#161616 1px solid;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.section p a{
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    min-width:180px;
}

.section p a:hover{
    background-color:#c569f2;
}

/* ---------- SubSection ---------- */

.accordion .subsection.large:target div + p + div {
        overflow: auto;
}

.subsection p{
    color:#FFFfff;
    text-align:right;
    min-width:200px;
    background-color:#3d3d3d;
    font-size:12px;
    font-size-adjust:inherit;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border-top:#161616 1px solid;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.subsection p a{
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    min-width:180px;
}

.subsection p a:hover{
    background-color:#c39bda;
}

/* ---------- Sidebar ---------- */

#sidebar{
    float: right;
    right: 0px;
    background-color:#161616;
    position:fixed;
    width:20%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    top:0px;
}

#side-menu{
    right: 0px;
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    height:75%;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    min-height:600px;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="side-menu" class="accordion">
  <div id="menu-portfolio" class="section">
    <p>
      <a href="#menu-portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </p>
    <div id="submenu-branding" class="subsection">
      <p>
        <a href="#submenu-branding">Branding</a>
      </p>
      <div>
        <p>
          <a href="google.com">Content</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu-about" class="section">
    <p>
      <a href="#menu-about">About</a>
    </p>
    <div>
      <p><a href="google.com">Contact</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu-contact" class="section">
    <p>
      <a href="#menu-contact">Contact</a>
    </p>
    <div>
      <p><a href="google.com">Content</a></p>

      <p><a href="google.com">Content2</a></p>

      <p><a href="google.com">Content3</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The result I am getting right now is that the first accordion works but when it opens it displays ALL the content (the BRANDING div and the CONTENT div). When I click BRANDING it collapses the first menu again. To note: the first accordion menu is the one that I am trying to add a sub-accordion to, the second is the accordion as built off of the fiddle, and the third is the second accordion with multiple subsections.

Hope all of that makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a fiddle.

Comment: If you had really understood how this works, then you would know that it is not possible to use this approach for more than one level (not without writing repeating markup)  – because only one element can be in `:target` state at any time – so this: _“When I click BRANDING it collapses the first menu again”_ __must__ happen.

Comment: _“but when it opens it displays ALL the content ”_ – that’s because the selector `.accordion :target p + div` targets (in the first case) the `div` directly underneath `#menu-portfolio` as well as the `div` inside that first `div`. While this could be fixed using the child selector, the problem mentioned before can not (not without writing nonsensical markup).

Comment: CBroe - I realize I don't fully understand which is why I come here for help and advice. Since I'm teaching myself in my spare time I realize for those more proficient in this my questions are probably fairly fundamental. That said I believe I understand what youre saying. Do you have any recommendations (not asking for code, but terms or resources to use to learn from)?

Comment: @LokeshSuthar - http://jsfiddle.net/m4ADf/1/